# How to parse attribute from savon response

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, savon

I am posting the soap response I am working with at the bottom.
I need to grab the `BodyType="HTML"` attribute from `<t:Body BodyType="HTML">`

Doing `response.body` turns the entire thing into a hash and there is no sign of `BodyType="HTML"` in that.

Doing `response.doc.css("t|Body")` generates the error: `Undefined namespace prefix: //t:Body (Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError)` because I don't see that namespace declaration in the XML.

Doing `response.doc.css("Body")` return blank.

What can I do to retrieve the value of `BodyType`?

Since there is no point in posting the code that makes the secure/private soap request, I am posting some basic code that reads in the XML from a flat file:

```
require 'savon'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("tmp.xml"))
puts @doc.css("t|Body")
```

And here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="629" MinorBuildNumber="8" Version="V2016_07_13"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:Message>
              <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADE2NjQyMjVlLWNhY2UtNDNiMS04MzgxLWZiNzEyNzA0NDgwNQBGAAAAAACLt5QBAQ/GRYv+vEXkY5vLBwA6ksGFFTICTbjFW6e9FfRGAAAAAAEMAAA6ksGFFTICTbjFW6e9FfRGAAAu8FruAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAAA6ksGFFTICTbjFW6e9FfRGAAAu9iR3"/>
              <t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkADE2NjQyMjVlLWNhY2UtNDNiMS04MzgxLWZiNzEyNzA0NDgwNQAuAAAAAACLt5QBAQ/GRYv+vEXkY5vLAQA6ksGFFTICTbjFW6e9FfRGAAAAAAEMAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA=="/>
              <t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>
              <t:Subject>From test</t:Subject>
              <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
              <t:Body BodyType="HTML">Hello world</t:Body>
            </t:Message>
          </m:Items>
        </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: When asking about code, please reduce your input to the absolute minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything else wastes our time by forcing us to do it and potentially confuses anyone else looking for a similar solution. Please read "[mcve]" and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces can really muddy the waters.

By default, Nokogiri will look in the root node for namespace declarations so `t|Body` would work if `xmlns:t` had been defined in the root node.

But, because it wasn't, you have to use [`collect_namespaces`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document:collect_namespaces) to tell Nokogiri to search the document and build a hash of all the ones it found. Then you can pass that hash to `search`, `css`, `at` or any of the search methods:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <t:Message>
        <t:Body BodyType="HTML">Hello world</t:Body>
      </t:Message>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
EOT
ns = doc.collect_namespaces # => {"xmlns:s"=>"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "xmlns:t"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types", "xmlns:m"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"}
doc.at("t|Body", ns)['BodyType'] # => "HTML"
```

If you read the documentation for `collect_namespaces` you'll see that there's a potential problem where the keys returned could overwrite previously found declarations. If there were such a problem you could work around that by finding the `s:Body` node, then its first child-element then collecting the namespaces:

```
ns = doc.at('s|Body').first_element_child.namespaces 
# => {"xmlns:m"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages", "xmlns:t"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types", "xmlns:s"=>"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"}
```

That will result in a hash of only the namespaces inside `s:Body`: